# Raspicam API cannot compile programs

Tags: raspbian, camera

I have installed the raspicam api as per the instructions. There were no errors.

Now when I try to compile the example programs or any of my own programs using the API, I get the compile error:

```
fatal error: raspicam.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried updating the pi, restarting and installing previous versions. I also copied the .h files into /usr/local/lib/raspicam as the header files were not there as the readme suggested they should be.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: try to compile with `-raspicam` `gcc program.c -o program -lraspicam`

Comment: I'm embarrassed that was the answer, but thanks! I forgot to add it into my program's makefile. The example cmake chain clearly misses this too... Thanks again!

Comment: @MakhloufGHARBI I don't understand -raspicam part, also could you elaborate your solution? Thanks!